# How to protect the wires when the electrical box is mounted on a 2x4 stud?

Tags: wiring, switch

The interior 2x4 wall will have drywall on both sides. The light switch box has wires coming in/out are almost to the back of the stud. How do I protect them as they will not be 1 1/4 inch from the wall?

Answer (score 2):

Generally this isn't a concern. It's a very common scenario, and inspectors don't usually call for steel plates or anything. Use caution when hanging your drywall in those areas and don't worry about it.